# A Question about Product Measures

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, product-measure

I'm working on the following problem:

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on subsets of $X$ and $\mathcal{N}$  be a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$. Discuss the validity of the following statement: $A \times B \in \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ iff $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B \in \mathcal{N}$.

I have the forward direction. My book is saying the reverse direction is false. I have a "proof" that it's true. I trust the book, so what's wrong with my "proof"?

> To show $A \times B \in \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ check that the $x$-sections and $y$-sections are $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{M}$ respectively. $(A\times B)_x = \{y \in Y : (x,y) \in A\times B\} = B$ and $B$ is in $\mathcal{N}$ by assumption. Same for the y-section. Thus we are done.

For the forward direction:

> Assume $A \times B \in \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$. The x-section $(A\times B)_x = \{y \in Y : (x,y) \in A\times B\} = B$. $B \in \mathcal{N}$ beacuse of Proposition 2.34 in Folland. (This reads: if $E \in \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ then $E_x \in \mathcal{N}$ for all $x \in X$ and $E_y \in \mathcal{M}$ for all $y \in Y$) Same argument for the y-section.

Answer (score 1):

You have proved that $A \in \mathcal M$ and $B \in \mathcal N$ implies $A\times B \in \mathcal M \otimes \mathcal N$. I don't see any proof of the converse. It is the converse that is false. For example if we take both $X$ and $Y$ to be  the real line with the Borel sigma algebra then $\Delta=\{(x,x):x \in \mathbb R\}$ belongs to $\mathcal M \otimes \mathcal N$ but it cannot be written as $A\times B$.

Comment: I provided a proof for the forward direction. Is $\Delta$ open in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $\Delta$ is closed in $\mathbb R^{2}$ and this implies that it belongs to $\mathcal B \otimes \mathcal B$. @yoshi

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why $\Delta$ cannot be written as $A \times B$ could you elaborate or provide a reference?

Comment: If $\Delta =A \times B$ what are $A$ and $B$? For any $x \in X$ note that $(x,x) \in \Delta=A\times B$ which implies $x \in A$. Thus every point of $X$ is in $A$ and $A=X$. Similarly, $B=Y$. But then $A\times B =X\times B$ contradicting the fact that $\Delta =A \times B$. (I am assuming that $X$ or $Y$ has at least two points). @yoshi

Comment: I think it should be $A \times B = X \times Y$, right? I dont think this is correct. The X-section and Y-sections of $\Delta$ are in $\mathcal{B}$ (because they are single points and single points are in Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$). So $\Delta$ is in $\mathcal{B} \otimes \mathcal{B}$. Right?

Comment: @yoshi That was a typo. I meant $A \times B=X\times Y$.